# Is KAOS goal modeling used in the industry?

Tags: requirements, modeling

[KAOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KAOS_(software_development)) is a goal-modeling strategy that is widely taught in the academia.

I have seen that almost no known diagramming software supports it except [objectiver](https://www.objectiver.com/), which was developed by the same group that invented KAOS.

Is it used in the industry? Are any FAANG/Fortune 500 companies using it?

Comment: Formal goal modelling in any notation is not part of mainstream software development practices. I would challenge the assertion that KAOS is widely tought. However, there continues to be an academic community interested in KAOS and i\*.

Comment: @amon So there's only an academic interest but nobody actually uses it? I'm currently studying about it in a joint degree by Carnegie Mellon & Coimbra University. I'm guessing that if a 4th-in-the-world university like CMU teaches it, other universities tend to follow.

Comment: I've never seen it used in industry.  Methodologies like waterfall and iterative development are far more common.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. @RobertHarvey, KAOS isn't an SDLC, it is a requirements engineering methodology.

Comment: I did not downvote yet, but when a post starts with an unfounded (and most probably wrong) claim just copied from an unfounded Wikipedia article, I think that doesn't give a good first impression on a question.

Comment: @DocBrown Simply googling "KAOS goal modeling site:*.edu" gives plenty of different institutions teaching it in one way or another, and quite a few different presentations. Moreover the `.edu` namespace is only for US-based institutions, and only there I've found over 10 different universities looking at the first 2 pages. But that's not the point of the question.

Comment: Every niche little methodology has a multi-page Wikipedia article, so if you find a methodology which only has 6 sentences on Wikipedia and whose page hasn't been touched in 6 years, you can be pretty much guaranteed that it is dead and not used by anybody, anywhere.

Comment: While I might be using my terminology a bit loosely, my claim still stands.  I have not even heard the word KAOS in an industry context.  Shouldn't be all that surprising; there are many things taught in universities that are essentially worthless.

Comment: Alright, so the answer is pretty much no. Thanks @JörgWMittag, @ Robert, @ amon. If you wish you can post it as an answer. By the way, the wikipedia page hasn't been touched in ~14 years. The recent edits are just bots. Good idea for checking! :-)

Comment: The links are pdfs..

Comment: @Ewan What do you mean? They are PDFs of university lectures from many different universities, yes.

Comment: @Bharel: well, you asked us where the downvotes were motivated from, and I gave you my best guess. What I am telling you is if you want to avoid such downvotes in the future, you could try to find some better wording. Instead writing *"strategy that is widely taught in the academia."* I would have written *"...strategy of which that Wikipedia article claims it is widely taught in the academia"*, and maybe added some info about your search results.

Comment: ... of course, that is still no guarantee for a question not to get a downvote. In fact, 90% of the questions asked in this site gets at least one downvote, that is a community issue here.

Comment: @DocBrown oh thank you! I mistakenly thought of your message as a harsh criticism but you're just trying to help :-) I'll take you suggestion next time. Highly appreciated!

Comment: @Bharel I mean just by looking at the Wikipedia page you can tell no one uses it. where are the links to websites promoting the idea and selling courses? where is the outline of its principles? where is the discussion about related methodology? where are the edits since 2007?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fair to assume the answer is **no**.

Google searches seem to find plenty of universities such as [Michigan State](http://www.cse.msu.edu/%7Ecse870/Lectures/Notes/02c-kaos-goal-modeling-bhc-v3-notes.pdf), [PACE](http://csis.pace.edu/%7Emarchese/CS775/Lectures/775L6b.ppt), [Louvain](https://www.cs.scranton.edu/%7Emccloske/courses/se507/vanLams_kaos_presentation.pdf) and others teaching it, but there are no available up-to-date toolsets, the respective [KAOS Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KAOS_(software_development)) is small and wasn't updated for more than 10 years, and from a quick Google search and comments on this question, it seems like the industry is not aware of its existence.

Keep in mind it is hard to know every single Fortune 500's internal policies, but due to the findings above, there's a good probability that none of them use it.